# How to process string stream that is intended to look like a table to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Was wondering if someone might be able to refer to a previous solution to similar past-posted query, or may have pointers as to how to solve below:

Using an API that produces string stream as follows:

```
[           name_str1  name_str2  name_str3  123456
01.12.2020  12345.35   493.2      3494.99    45874.3
02.12.2020  43.35      4234.2     354.99     454324.3
03.12.2020  345.35     4287.2     784.99     76.3
04.12.2020  87.35      443.2      567.99     46.3

[4 rows x 4 columns]]
```

Converted to Numpy, looks like:

```
[[          name_str1  name_str2  name_str3  123456
01.12.2020  12345.35   493.2      3494.99    45874.3
02.12.2020  43.35      4234.2     354.99     454324.3
03.12.2020  345.35     4287.2     784.99     76.3
04.12.2020  87.35      443.2      567.99     46.3

[4 rows x 4 columns]]]
```

In Pandas df, looks like:

```
                                            0
0       name_str1   name_str2.....

with df.info() giving:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0   1 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: nnn bytes
None
```

I would like to convert the API output (string) object to Panda DataFrame with name_str1, name_str2...,123456 as columns, and using the dates as row index to time-series in the DataFrame 4x4 data/table body

Would anyone know of an approach that would handle any columns names returned, and number of columns, returned to produce a NxN DataFrame ?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This does work, it is a bit of a hack to make the first square bracket work

```
s = """[           name_str1  name_str2  name_str3  123456
01.12.2020  12345.35   493.2      3494.99    45874.3
02.12.2020  43.35      4234.2     354.99     454324.3
03.12.2020  345.35     4287.2     784.99     76.3
04.12.2020  87.35      443.2      567.99     46.3

[4 rows x 4 columns]]"""

df = (pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep="\s+", skipfooter=1, engine="python")
 .rename(columns={"[":"date"})
 .assign(date=lambda dfa: pd.to_datetime(dfa.date))
 .set_index("date")
)
```

| date | name_str1 | name_str2 | name_str3 | 123456 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-12 00:00:00 | 12345.4 | 493.2 | 3494.99 | 45874.3 |
| 2020-02-12 00:00:00 | 43.35 | 4234.2 | 354.99 | 454324 |
| 2020-03-12 00:00:00 | 345.35 | 4287.2 | 784.99 | 76.3 |
| 2020-04-12 00:00:00 | 87.35 | 443.2 | 567.99 | 46.3 |